# How to use Stack in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a project where I'm using Stack during the implementation of shortest path algorithm. However, I keeps getting the same element out of the Stack while I'm trying to pop all the elements out of it. I'm not sure if I pushed the elements in the wrong way, or popped in the wrong way, or even initialized in the wrong way. So help me out fellas, here is my code:

```
    Stack<Point> path = new Stack<>();

    public void addToContour(Point p){

    if(contour.isEmpty()){
        contour.add(p);
        Log.i(TAG, "contour is empty");
    } else{
        Log.i(TAG, "contour not empty");

        findPath(p);  // see the body of this function below

        while(!path.empty()){
            Point pathP;
            pathP = path.pop();  //pop the elements added in findPath()
            contour.add(pathP);
            Log.i(TAG, "point: " + pathP.x + " " + pathP.y);
        }

    }

    computePath(p);

}
```

In function findpath():

```
public void  findPath(Point point){

    if (!contour.isEmpty()) {

        Point p = point;

        int direction = toParent[(int) p.y][(int) p.x];
        while (direction != 10) {
            path.push(p);  // push elements into "path"
            p.x = p.x + shift.get(direction).x;
            p.y = p.y + shift.get(direction).y;
            direction = toParent[(int) p.y][(int) p.x];
            Log.i(TAG, "point: " + p.x + " " + p.y);
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see I have "Log" for debugging in both while loops. In the one where I pushed the stack, it indicates that all elements are different, however, in the other while loop I keep getting the same element out of it.

Comment: Should it be `findPath(path)`?

Comment: @mash sorry, this just made me realized that I need to paste the entire function, otherwise its confusing. hold on..